# Simplest way to extract Option from Scala collections

Tags: scala, collections, option-type

Imagine you have a `Map[Option[Int], String]` and you want to have a `Map[Int, String]` discarding the entry which contain `None` as the key.

Another example, that should be somehow similar is `List[(Option[Int], String)]` and transform it to `List[(Int, String)]`, again discarding the tuple which contain `None` as the first element.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`collect` is your friend here:

## example data definition

```
val data = Map(Some(1) -> "data", None -> "")
```

## solution for Map

```
scala> data collect { case ( Some(i), s) => (i,s) }
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> data)
```

## the same approach works for a list of tuples

```
scala> data.toList collect { case ( Some(i), s) => (i,s) }
res5: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,data))
```